# C# WPF Databinding class object list to listBoxItem which is create as separate control (xaml)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, xaml

I have one big problem :(. I create separate (XAML) control which I use as ListBoxItem and I want binding to this Listbox, list of my class object. If I don't have separate ListBoxItem it's not a problem to bind this data but I must do it like that. 
    Below this post I upload simple version of code which show you what exacty I want make.

- UserControl1 (CS)

  ```cs
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.Windows;
  using System.Windows.Controls;
  using System.Windows.Data;
  using System.Windows.Documents;
  using System.Windows.Input;
  using System.Windows.Media;
  using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
  using System.Windows.Navigation;
  using System.Windows.Shapes;

  namespace WpfApplication2
  {
      /// <summary>
      /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
      /// </summary>
      public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
      {
          public UserControl1()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
          }
          public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
              DependencyProperty.Register("Id", typeof(string),
              typeof(UserControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

          public string Id
          {
              get { return GetValue(TextProperty).ToString(); }
              set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
          }

          public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty1 =
      DependencyProperty.Register("name1", typeof(string),
      typeof(UserControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

          public string name1
          {
              get { return GetValue(TextProperty1).ToString(); }
              set { SetValue(TextProperty1, value); }
          }

          public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty2 =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Surname", typeof(string),
      typeof(UserControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

          public string Surname
          {
              get { return GetValue(TextProperty2).ToString(); }
              set { SetValue(TextProperty2, value); }
          }
          public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty3 =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Age", typeof(string),
      typeof(UserControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

          public string Age
          {
              get { return GetValue(TextProperty3).ToString(); }
              set { SetValue(TextProperty3, value); }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Main Window XAML

  ```cs
  <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="222" Margin="144,571,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="404">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <local:UserControl1 FontStretch="Medium" Id="{Binding Path=id}" name="{Binding Path=Name1}" Age="{Binding Path=age}" Surname="blabla"/>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
  ```

- Main Window CS

```xml
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
      public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<zdarzenia> zdarz_list = new List<zdarzenia>(); 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();       
        }

               public class person
        {

            public string id;
            public string name;
            public string surname;
            public string age;
            public person(string Id, string Name, string Surname, string Age)
            {
                id = Id;
                name = Name;
                surname = Surname;
                age = Age;
            }
        }
        public List<person> list = new List<person>();

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            list.Add(new person("1", "Ana", "Sophia", "35"));
            list.Add(new person("2", "Jack", "Black", "40"));
            listBox1.ItemsSource = list;

        }

    }
}
```

UserControl1.XAML is in the link I can't upload this part of code

Sorry I have some problems with certificate in a place where I work and I can't paste code properly. Here is better version if you want:

http://ideone.com/bm5XSP

http://ideone.com/HRTLlB

I will be grateful for your help
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the problem? You can start with [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this way you have higher chances to get answer (nobody likes wall of code) and won't have problem with employer.